# how to open rear camera by default in quickblox

Tags: android, video, quickblox

I am using QuickBlox sdk for video calling in android application, whenever i make a video call to my selected user front camera is opened as default.I want to change that to rear camera by default whenever i make video call. please help.

Comment: you should show some code to allow us to help you

Answer (score 2):

QuckBlox doesn't have API to set default camera but you can try switch camera to rear immediately after start call.